# Simple login test, translated from java to python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, integration-testing

I'm reading on how to write proper testing suites [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html). So I'm trying to follow the selenium example in the [docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) which is in Java; I'm trying to translate it to Python since my app is written in Python.

So I translated the example like so:

```
class LoginPage(unittest.TestCase):
    FE_URL = os.getenv('FE_URL')
    SERVER_URL = os.getenv('SERVER_URL')
    
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.selenium = driver

    def find_button_by_text(self, text):
        buttons = self.selenium.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
        for btn in buttons:
            if text in btn.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
                return btn

    def login_page(self):
        self.selenium.get(self.FE_URL)
        WebDriverWait(self.selenium, MAX_WAIT).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "login"))
        )
        return self.selenium
    
    def type_username(self, username):
        username_locator = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("user[email]")
        username_locator.send_keys(username)
        return self.selenium

    def type_password(self, password):
        password_locator = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("user[password]")
        password_locator.send_keys(password)
        return self.selenium

    def submit_login(self):
        login_locator = self.find_button_by_text("Continue")
        login_locator.click()
        return self.selenium

    def submit_login_expecting_failure(self):
        self.login_page()
        self.submit_login()
        return self.selenium

    def login_as(self, username, password):
        login_page = self.login_page()
        self.type_username(username)
        self.type_password(password)
        return self.submit_login()
```

and then the actual test is here:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    USER_NAME = os.getenv('USER_NAME')
    PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
    

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(MyTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        # cls.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.selenium, MAX_WAIT)
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(MyTest, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        login_page = LoginPage(self.selenium)
        main_page = login_page.login_as(self.USER_NAME, self.PASSWORD)
        WebDriverWait(main_page, MAX_WAIT).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Create alert"))
        )

    def test_failed_login(self):
        login_page = LoginPage(self.selenium)
        page = login_page.submit_login_expecting_failure()
        alert = WebDriverWait(page, MAX_WAIT).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "alert-danger"))
        )
        self.assertIn("Invalid Email or Password", alert.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The test works. Did I understand this correctly that the driver is setup in the actual test class and not in the `LoginPage`?

Did I hide the actual mechanics of the test correctly? I am using `WebDriverWait` in the `LoginPage` class to wait till the page is loaded. I see this as kind of an assert replacement but I am not sure how else to wait for the page to have finished loading.

Comment: Do `FE_URL` and `SERVER_URL` take values that point to a publicly-accessible server you can share with us for the purposes of testing?

Comment: those are only localhost values, as in `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3001` I put them in env variables cause I thought this is how you are supposed to do it

Comment: No that's fine, you've done the right thing. It just means that I can't test your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest miss here is that `LoginPage`, though it is perhaps fine as a test utility class, is clearly not a `TestCase` and should not inherit from that.

This loop:

```
    buttons = self.selenium.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
    for btn in buttons:
        if text in btn.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
            return btn
```

should not be needed, and you should be able to write a single selector that accomplishes the same thing. Without access to your DOM I don't know what that's going to be, precisely.

Your pattern of `return self.selenium` isn't particularly useful, since `MyTest` already has a reference to its own `self.selenium`; so all of those functions can just be `None`-returns.

For Python 3 you should no longer be passing parameters into `super()`.